# Асинхронная обработка нажатий кнопок

Tags: c++, qt

Приведу упрощенный пример.

Есть программа с GUI на Qt. По клику по кнопке выполняется некая долгая функция. Когда мы жмем на кнопку она "залипает" и "отлипает" только после выхода из функции.

Как выйти из данной ситуации? Пока вариант только повесить выполнение этой функции на таймер.

```
void Form::OnClick()
{
    QTimer timer = new QTimer();
    timer->setInterval( 1 );
    connect( timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(HardFunc()) );
}
```

`HardFunc` - та самая долгая функция

Comment: Обработчик таймера выполняется в том же потоке, что и GUI, так что смысла в вашем коде никакого.

Comment: @zenden2k, если HardFunc минуту, то все вилы? gui эту минуту не шелохнется?

Comment: да именно так. Вам нужен отдельный поток для тяжелой задачи, ниже дан совет, как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) для исполнения Вашей задачи асинхронно:

```
auto future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &Form::HardFunc);
```

`future`, которое вернёт функция может быть использована для ожидания завершения задачи в дальнейшем.